# how i can set custom methods for mongoose model with @nestjs/mongoose package?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I want to set custom model methods in order to edit fields, which are a complex structure. For example, in order to switch the status of complete todo.

Something like this:

```js
@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: [{ title: String, complete: Boolean }], default: [] })
  todos: Todo[];
}

const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

UserSchema.methods.toggleComleteTodo = (id: string) => {
    // code...
}
```

What i do wrong? Where can I find out about the correct code? In docs nestjs nothing about custom mongoose methods = (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a small example hot I managed this in nestJS with `mongoose`

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { User } from './user.interface';
import { generateCode } from '../utils/helpers';
import { SMS_FROM, Twilio } from '../utils/twilio.lib';

const SALT = 10;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['patient', 'doctor', 'admin'],
      required: true,
      default: 'patient',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

UserSchema.pre<User>('save', async function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
  try {
    this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, SALT);
    console.log('pre save hook triggered');
    this.isDocUpdated = true;
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});

UserSchema.method({
  validatePassword: async function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
  },
});

export { UserSchema };
```

you also have to create Interface for User schema and cast the Model type to UserInterface when you inject your model

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { IUser } from './user.interface';


export class UsersService {
  private client: ClientProxy;
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<IUser>,
  ) {}
}
```